# Capybara scenarios in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, integration-testing, capybara, acceptance-testing

I have a strange problem with acceptance tests, capybara showing me only first scenario in a  browser, all other are just run in back-end and i see a blank page for some reason(but they pass and failed normally). My config is:

```rails
require 'capybara'

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome
Capybara.run_server = true
Capybara.server_port = 7000
Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost:#{Capybara.server_port}"
```

`tests`:

```rails
feature 'f1' do

  background do
    @user = create(:user)
    visit "/"
    fill_in 'Email', :with => @user.email
    fill_in 'Password', :with => 'password'
    click_button 'Sign In'
  end

  scenario "sc1" do
    click_link '1'
    click_link '2'
    click_link '3'
    page.should have_content('120')
  end

  scenario "sc2" do
    click_link '4'
    click_link '5'
    click_link '6'
    page.should have_content('110')
  end

end
```

`gemfile`:

```rails
group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '~> 2.8.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.8.0'

  gem 'shoulda', '~> 2.11.3'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'

  gem 'capybara', '~> 1.1.2'
  gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.5.2'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

So I can see only `sc1` running in browser, `sc2` and all others are just run in background and i see a blank page in chrome. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone will meet same problem:

```rails
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before do
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
    Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome
    Capybara.run_server = true
    Capybara.server_port = 7000
    Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost:#{Capybara.server_port}"
  end
end
```

placing this in `before` block does the trick